# Python Compare Two lists with a loop and if a match is found run a few codes, and return back to the loop to test if there is another match

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I am building a program in python. I have two lists and I want to loop through each of them to see if the elements are equal if they are I want to remove the one element from the list and I want to run a few codes. When this is done I want to return back to the loop to compare the lists again. until one list is empty and the program will continue.

I tried this but just can not get my mind to unblock it!  Thank you.

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [28,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in x:
for a in y:
while i == a:
x.remove(i)

###### How do I tell python to return to the first loop??

Comment: Its seems like you trying to get the union of two lists..why don't you try z = x.union(y)

Comment: Not really the union, because the two lists will be identical either way. What I want is a way to loop through both of them and compare each element, while i == x run a few codes remove i from x, and loop through the lists again until x is empty.

Comment: Also to return to 1st loop..you can try break or flag approaches

Comment: Can you demonstrate with an example, please?

Comment: Not sure but something like this 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [28,1,2,3,4,5,6]
flag=False
for i in x:
    flag=False
    for a in y:
        while i == a:
            x.remove(i)
            flag=True
        if(flag==True):
            break

initialize a var flag= false and once enter inside while loop makes it true...similarly, make if the condition on 2nd for loop to come out from it once it enter while loop

Comment: I still do not get what you mean. Can you perhaps share code example based on my example?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the ask, but it looks you want to loop over `y` and compare every element against the next element in `x`, and so forth? If so then it looks like you will end up with `x = [7]` because that's the only element not present in `y`

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in the elements that match if they match, run a few codes, and move on to the next elements that match again until no elements match

Comment: hmm.. based on that it definitely seems like @MukulKumar's `x.union(y)` approach is the way to go? Basically get a list of all common elements between both lists, and iterate over that new list and run a block of code on each result

Answer (score 0):

Use flag approch

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [28,1,2,3,4,5,6]
flag=False
for i in x:
    flag=False
    for a in y:
        while i == a:
            x.remove(i)
            flag=True
        if(flag==True):
            break
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, i is not changing to the next value in x, I need it to loop through x until x is empty

Comment: Then I suggest to use for loop as for i in range(0, len(x)): and then to try.

Make similar change in y's for loop also